# Unable to view entire text in input field in iPAD and iPhone

Tags: css, scroll

I am using text input field in my html page. When the input is more then the input field size, unable to view the remaining text. In Android phones i can able to view the entire text by scrolling using the property "Overflow: scroll", the same style/property is not working in iPAD and iPhone.

Note : Applying -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch  is also not working.

```html
<input type="text" value="this is my input content that exceeds the limit in device" style="width:100px; overflow:scroll"/>
```

Comment: style="width:100%; overflow:scroll"/

Comment: Hi @harkeshkumar, Thanks for suggesion, i need to use limited width only not the 100% width, do you have any other idea?

Comment: than do max-width:350px; width:100%;

Comment: what is your limition for width

Comment: @harkeshkumar, since it should be displayed in  mobile, width is only 100px, it will be better if we have scrolling like functionality inside the text box, can you have any idea

Comment: @seravanan Bro if you want to scroll then change text to textarea and fix the column height  and all